# How to provide infinite adding of rows to DataGridView object in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got a problem with providing infinite adding of data to a `DataGridView` object.

I need to write a code which will every time I tap the button it will add a new row with the information which I will enter in the text box.

Other I have already provided, I will not write a code snippet here but if required I can write.

Any tips are appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Webforms? Winforms? ASP.NET MVC ? ASP.NET Core MVC? Blazor ? Please **at least** tell us what your environment is!

Comment: Winforms, also there I need to display a list of objects. Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` all you need to do to "display a list of objects" (let's say the *objects* are of type `MyDataObject`) is make a new `BindingList<MyDataObject>` and assign it to the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`. This will cause the DGV to generate columns for any public properties exposed in your class.

To specifically answer your question about how the "infinite adding of rows" works, just make sure the `AllowUserToAddRows` property of the DGV set `true`. Adding the rows and inline editing of the values is built into the `DataGridView` control without having to roll your own version of that functionality.

I would provide a code snippet for doing this but you'd have to edit your post and show what the class object looks like that you're trying to list.